# How to apply caching in helper method in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, outputcache

I have a helper method in my application and i have applied output caching on it

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "DetailsId")]
public static Dictionary<string, object> GetData(int DetailsId)
{

}
```

but on every request this function is called.

I want to know can i apply Output Cache on Helper method? If yes then how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Output Cache attribute needs to be on an ActionResult not on a static or non static method.

For instance

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "DetailsId")]
public ViewResult GetData(int DetailsId)
{

}
```

In short you cannot use the OutputCache attribute this level use something along the lines of the Cache Object:

```
public Dictionary<string,object> GetData(int DetailsId)
{
 //Try to get object from cache
var model = (Dictionary<string,object>)HttpContextBase.Current.Cache["Data_"+DetailsId];
if(model==null)
{
HttpContextBase.Current.Cache["Data_"+DetailsId] = model_from_store;
return model_from_store;
}
else
return model;
}
```